# Rijndael in class library (package) not available for .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dnx

Please help me.
Where to find the Rijndael Security Cryptography in .NET Core?

What dependency I must to include in my class library (Package) project?

Answer (score 12):

The Rijndael implementation is not (yet) ported to .NET Core. You could use AES (which is a subset of Rijndael) using the [`System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms) package which targets `netstandard1.3`:

```
var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create();
```

Note: you should only add this package dependency to the `netstandard1.3` TFM, as it exists in the core library of the full framework already:

```
"netstandard1.3": {
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms": "4.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I already have a data that encrypt with Rijndael algorithm. Is AES have same algorithm with Rijndael ? If  no, I have to re encrypt the data again. :(. Hope it can be implemented yet in netcore.

Comment: @zenixgrace AES is Rijndael with a 16 byte block size set. If your data was encrypted with Rijndael with a 16 byte block size you can use AES to decrypt it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked in System.Security.  You will need to add an assembly reference to this DLL.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael x = System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael.Create();
```

Check here:

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That MSDN link is for NET 4.6, he's asking for .NET Core/ASP.NET Core 1.0

Comment: in dnx451, is available, but not for dotnet5.4