# Simple String Encryption without Dependencies

Tags: c#

I need a simple algorithm to encrypt / decrypt a string. Something like Base64 but a little more secure. It is not mission critical.
All I need is some string manipulation. Not as easy as copy the string and make it human readable using a simple base 64 decoder.

#### Why not using AES?

Since my app is created using .NET Core, it runs on windows and mac. **The problem i am facing is that in order to use `System.Security` on mac, i need openssl to be installed.** Since i dont have sudo access, i cant install it.

So here are the requirements:

- Simple String Encryption
- No Dependencies on `System.Security.*`

Ive read [Simple insecure two-way "obfuscation" for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-two-way-encryption-for-c-sharp) but there is no solution without dependencies.

Comment: Why not implement some simple bitshifting and wrap the result in Base64?

Comment: If you have such a solution feel free to post it as a answer. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tested the managed version of the crypto implementations? Like, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx. I would assume that they don't rely on external dependencies, however I'm not sure.

Comment: On a Mac you do not need openssl to be installed to e installed ignorer to use AES, use Common Crypto by including Security.framework. Common Crypto is just "C" code and uses whatever hardware encryption is available.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are looking for obfuscation rather than security, you could XOR the string with a constant or the output of a PRNG initialized with a constant seed.

Example with constant:

```
byte xorConstant = 0x53;

string input = "foo";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    data[i] = (byte)(data[i] ^ xorConstant);
}
string output = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

To decode:

```
byte xorConstant = 0x53;
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    data[i] = (byte)(data[i] ^ xorConstant);
}
string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted to post. dam you. +1.

Comment: Here is the problem, if there is a string of 0's (or even one) the string constant will be immediately known.

Comment: @zaph, With any known plaintext the constant is known.  That is why it is unquestionably unsecure.  Further, there are only 256 possible keys, so you can brute force it trivially.  It is not meant to be secure.

Comment: Perhaps I an more tuned to this because a co-worker "encrypted" some data that had leading zeros, when I saw the output I immediately knew the key without even trying.

Comment: nice answer but the code has simem problems the solution is`for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)` and `data[i] = (byte)(data[i] ^ xorConstant);`

Answer (score 2):

All the asymmetric and symmetric encryption methods reside in `System.Security` namespaces. From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795103/encrypt-string-in-net-core):

> The symmetric encryption options available in .NET Core are:
>
> - AES (System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create())
> - 3DES (System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDES.Create())
>
> And for asymmetric encryption
>
> - RSA (System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create())

So it appears you will need `System.Security` at least.

**EDIT**: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-two-way-encryption-for-c-sharp) a nice SO question with a ton of functions relating to encryption. Note extensive usage of `System.Security` namespace classes and methods.

Comment: I agree with this answer. In fact if you do not want to include `System.Security`, the only other option is implementing it yourself or copy-pasting the encryption method you want from said namespace.

Comment: @AngelosChalaris Exactly - in fact, OP, why can you not copy and paste in the code from a security library? Here's a bunch of functions from an SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-two-way-encryption-for-c-sharp

Comment: The problem is that these methods don't work on mac without openssl being installed.

Comment: @dknaack *Why would you write an app for Mac in C# to begin with? Why not Java for example, which is better supported and much similar to C#?* You can always copy and alter the libraries from said namespaces, though, to work for Mac and it shouldn't be too much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Use [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA), it is actually reasonably secure.

Below is the entire source code from Wikipedia:

```
#include <stdint.h>

/* take 64 bits of data in v[0] and v[1] and 128 bits of key[0] - key[3] */

void encipher(unsigned int num_rounds, uint32_t v[2], uint32_t const key[4]) {
    unsigned int i;
    uint32_t v0=v[0], v1=v[1], sum=0, delta=0x9E3779B9;
    for (i=0; i < num_rounds; i++) {
        v0 += (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + key[sum & 3]);
        sum += delta;
        v1 += (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + key[(sum>>11) & 3]);
    }
    v[0]=v0; v[1]=v1;
}

void decipher(unsigned int num_rounds, uint32_t v[2], uint32_t const key[4]) {
    unsigned int i;
    uint32_t v0=v[0], v1=v[1], delta=0x9E3779B9, sum=delta*num_rounds;
    for (i=0; i < num_rounds; i++) {
        v1 -= (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + key[(sum>>11) & 3]);
        sum -= delta;
        v0 -= (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + key[sum & 3]);
    }
    v[0]=v0; v[1]=v1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something with BitShifting:

```
 var topSecret = "This is%&/(/ TopSecret 111!!";
 int shft = 5;
 string encrypted = topSecret.Select(ch => ((int) ch) << shft).Aggregate("", (current, val) => current + (char) (val*2));
 encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encrypted));
 string decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted)).Select(ch => ((int) ch) >> shft).Aggregate("", (current, val) => current + (char) (val/2));
```

Encrypted:

> 4ZSA4aiA4amA4bOA4KCA4amA4bOA4KWA4KaA4K+A4KiA4K+A4KCA4ZSA4a+A4bCA4ZOA4aWA4aOA4bKA4aWA4bSA4KCA4LGA4LGA4LGA4KGA4KGA

Decrypted again:

> This is%&/(/ TopSecret 111!!

**Note**

Not very pretty and very minimal. You can tweak the salts and Encodings to fit your needs.

Cheers